# Calculating Sample Size As Number of Days Needed For Significance?

Tags: standard-deviation, sample-size

I am trying to determine required number of days required to reach a significant result for a one-tailed independent sample test.  I have sales data **by day** for my test and control group.  The results per day are as follows:

- Group 1 Mean Sales Per day: 50,000
- Group 2 Mean Sales Per Day: 45,000
- Sigma/SD: 20,000
- Alpha: .2
- Power: .8
- Sample Size Required For 1 Tailed Test: 91

**My question: How do I interpret this number (91) exactly?**  91 days needed for the test?  Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you are doing a two-sample pooled t test of $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$ vs $H_a: \mu_1 > \mu_2$ at the 20% level of significance and wishing to detect a difference of $\delta = 5$ thousand with power 80%, where the standard deviations of the two independent groups are each $\sigma = 20$ thousand. You found that a sample size if $n = 91$ is required.

Here is output from Minitab statistical software confirming this result:

```
Power and Sample Size 

2-Sample t Test

Testing mean 1 = mean 2 (versus >)
Calculating power for mean 1 = mean 2 + difference
α = 0.2  
Assumed standard deviation = 20

            Sample  Target
Difference    Size   Power  Actual Power
         5      91     0.8      0.800402

The sample size is for each group.
```

As this output says, ***you would need 91 days in each group*** (91 in the treatment group and 91 in the control group, for a total of 182 days of observations).

[image]

---

*Notes:* (1) The *ratio* $\delta/\sigma = 5/20 = 0.25$
is crucial to this computation.

(2) The desired error probabilities are also crucial: if you want 5% and 95%, then the sample size required in each group increases to $n=347.$

```
Power and Sample Size 

2-Sample t Test

Testing mean 1 = mean 2 (versus >)
Calculating power for mean 1 = mean 2 + difference
α = 0.05  
Assumed standard deviation = 20


            Sample  Target
Difference    Size   Power  Actual Power
         5     275    0.90      0.900260
         5     347    0.95      0.950006
         5     506    0.99      0.990070

 The sample size is for each group.
```

[image]